# jQuery slider, plugin or custom made?

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm in need of some advice. I'm making a website for a friend who wants something "special" /ugh. It's an pretty normal site but he wants a slider on his page, no problem I said, but the slider has to display two and a half div's. (Horizontal slider btw)

The container of the slider div is 600px width. All the div's are 200px in width. He wants to show div number one // div number two // and half of div number 3 and when the user clicks on the right arrow he wants the contaner div to display the half of div number 2 // div number 3 // div number 4 // and half div number 5

So as you can see it's an pretty weird construction and I told him it would be better to stay with a normal slider but he's pretty obsessed about it so, you know. I though maybe you guys know if such an slider excists or maybe have some pointer as to how to fix it for myself.

Comment: If the `div`s all have fixed height, you can easily drop them all in a container with `overflow:hidden` and then use `scrollLeft` to move to the appropriate position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ try this one. I used it few times and it worked fine

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if anyone has already made something like this, but I would user ScrollTo (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) jquery plugin to implement it.

Comment: also a live example has been given at - http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/